# Laravel 5.6 - Route not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6 and trying to create a simple form to create a post. I have my web routes that looks like this..

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController')->middleware('auth');
```

My form looks like this...

```
<form action="{{route('posts@store')}}" method="POST">
    <input name="title" type="text">
</form>

And my PagesController looks like this

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $title = $request->input('title');
        $post->save();
    }
```

But I am getting the following error message..

```
Route [posts@store] not defined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is't it `route('posts.store')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) &  try following code.

```
<form action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST">
   <input name="title" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<form action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST">
    <input name="title" type="text">
</form>`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title= $request->input('title');//change
    $post->save();
}
```